# Spring: Does a method name in @Configuration class have any role

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // ...

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){ // other names for this method didn't work
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

}
```

Above is a part of my configuration class in a Spring MVC app.

When first testing `SessionLocalResolver`, I had the method name as `localResolver` (note the missing E) which caused the following exception: `Cannot change HTTP accept header – use a different locale resolution strategy`

My understanding, and obviously I was wrong, that the name of bean methods have no semantic value what so ever. But in this case, using any name other than `localeResolver` results in the above mentioned exceptions.

So my question: what is the role of the bean method name in an @Configuration class ? and where is that mentioned in the Spring documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific bean is looked up by name not type. `DispatcherServlet` looks for a bean named `localeResolver` and if it's not detected, it uses the default which is `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`. If you wanted to keep your original method name `localResolver`, you would just need to annotate it as

```
@Bean (name = "localeResolver")
public LocaleResolver localResolver() {...}
```

By default, a bean method name will be used as the bean name unless otherwise stated in the manner I presented above. In other words, the bean method name role is used to define the actual bean name. Hope this helps.